# Extract number with sign after string with stringr

Tags: r, regex, stringr

I have a list of strings. I want to return the number with its sign after the string "Kα1".

```
mylist <- c("Si/Si Kα1 pos-1 map data.tif", "Si/Si Kα1 pos1 map data.tif", "Si/Si Kα1 pos2 map data.tif", "Si/Si Kα1 pos3 map data.tif","Si/Si Kα1 pos4 map data.tif")
```

I've tried this:

```
library(stringr)
str_extract(mylist, "([^Kα1]\\d)")
#[1] "-1" "s1" "s2" "s3" "s4"
```

But there are letters before the numbers in that output. This is the result I want:

```
#[1] "-1" "1" "2" "3" "4"
```

Comment: You  want `str_extract(mylist, "-?(?<![Kα1])\\d+")`, I think. Do you mean to extract specific numbers only or any arbitrary ones?

Comment: thank you @Wiktor Stribiżew ! I just want the first number that occurs after the string. Your pattern gives me the correct output.

Comment: Please edit the question since now it sounds as if all you need is `-?\d+`. If you need to make sure there are no `K`, `α` and `1` before the value you need to extract, it should be written as a requirement.

Comment: So, my initial solution is wrong, I posted the right one.

Comment: Hi @Wiktor Stribiżew, your answer in the comment str_extract(mylist, "-?(?<![Kα1])\\d+")  worked, and you originally put that in the answer. Could it be changed back to this? I wanted to use the str_extract function but the new answer uses a different function.

Comment: That is not the solution to what you asked. `-?(?<![Kα1])\d+` is just wrong for the *return the number with its sign after the string `Kα1`* task.

Comment: Sorry @Wiktor Stribiżew I don't understand what is wrong with that solution, it is producing the correct output for me and answered the question I asked.

Comment: `-?(?<!α)\d+` will produce the same result. The fact that a regex works in some cases does not mean it is a solution, it may fail in others.

Comment: Ok thanks for explaining, can you instead use the str_extract function from StringR rather than regmatches in your answer? Or can you explain why you needed to change the function?

Comment: If you can't use anything but `stringr`, use `stringr::str_match(mylist, "Kα1.*?(-?\\d+)")[,2]` . `\K` is not supported in ICU regex used in stringr regex functions. We need a PCRE regex engine for that. And you can't use `str_extract(mylist, "(?<=Kα1.*?)-?\\d+")` because ICU regex engine does not support unknown width patterns in lookbehinds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
mylist <- c("Si/Si Kα1 pos-1 map data.tif", "Si/Si Kα1 pos1 map data.tif", "Si/Si Kα1 pos2 map data.tif", "Si/Si Kα1 pos3 map data.tif","Si/Si Kα1 pos4 map data.tif")
regmatches(mylist, regexpr("Kα1.*?\\K-?\\d+", mylist, perl=TRUE))
## => [1] "-1" "1"  "2"  "3"  "4"
## Or, a stringr solution variant:
stringr::str_match(mylist, "Kα1.*?(-?\\d+)")[,2]
## => [1] "-1" "1"  "2"  "3"  "4"
```

See the [R demo online](https://rextester.com/DNCQZ42093). See the [regex demo here](https://regex101.com/r/q1MdkL/1).

**Regex details**

- `Kα1` - a literal string
- `.*?` - any 0+ chars other than line break chars, as few as possible
- `\K` - a match reset operator that discards all text matched so far from the match memory buffer
- `-?` - an optional `-` symbol
- `\d+` - one or more digits.